# Rotate an object around a rotating object in JS

Tags: javascript, svg, rotation

I've got a little solar system Javascript project. I've figured out how to perfectly rotate SVG objects around the sun in a full circle without worring about x and y positions. (I know, planets rotate in ellipses, not important.)

This is the code for that.

```
 function rotate_point(pointX, pointY, originX, originY, ang) {
        ang =  ang * Math.PI / 180.0;
        return {
            x: Math.cos(ang) * (pointX-originX) - Math.sin(ang) * (pointY-originY) + originX ,
            y: Math.sin(ang) * (pointX-originX) + Math.cos(ang) * (pointY-originY) + originY 
        };} // rotate_point
```

I can't for the life of me rotate the moon around the earth though, it's because the earth itself is rotating and can't position it accurately enough. I't's in a perfectly circle but it'll never revolve from the earth's center as its axis, so it keeps bulging to a side. I've tried tweaking its x and y positions, rotation speed, nothing.

Can anyone see what problem there is in the code for me to perfectly rotate the moon around the earth?

Here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/yf3sgsu5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you are moving the Earth element before you attempt to do the Moon rotation.  So the centre of the moons orbit has changed when you do the moon part.  You get an elliptical orbit because the radius varies depending on whether the earth is moving towards or away from the moon.

You would either need to read the `cx,cy` of the Earth before you move it.  Or you can calculate the orbital positions independently (see below).

https://jsfiddle.net/yf3sgsu5/3/

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. The independent orbital positions are fun to play around with, thank you.